# Is there a way to force a deleted service handle to be released (Windows 10)?

Tags: service, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to use Windows Installer (MSI/msiexec) to upgrade a product installed by a non-MSI package.

My MSI is using a custom action DLL to exec the other package's uninstaller, then does a "normal" msi install, including installing and starting the service.

The non-MSI uninstaller uninstalls a service but although the service is marked as deleted its handle is held open so my MSI's install of the service is failing. The service handle is not released until msiexec exits. I had hoped/expected that the service handle would be released on exit from the old package's uninstaller, or failing that, on return from my custom action DLL, but until msiexec is finished the service is just marked as deleted.

I have to use the non-MSI package's uninstall mechanism so there's no way to avoid its service-uninstall.

What's the best way to deal with this? If possible I don't want to force the user to do two separate procedures, such as first running the non-MSI uninstall and second installing the MSI. That would no longer seem like an upgrade.

Is there a way to force a deleted service handle to be released?

Comment: You could force a reboot after the previous uninstall and then set it to restart the install after reboot.

Comment: thanks Doc good suggestion .. in the end the guy who coded the DLL found some workaround so we avoided having to restart